# Do the specs of my new battery need to exactly match the old?

Tags: battery, replace, parts

I have the following values on my car battery:

```
12v 71ah 580cca
```

When looking for a new battery, do I need to ensure I get one with those exact values, or can it be different?  For example, would the following work?

```
12v 61ah 480cca?
```

Or maybe

```
12v 81ah 680cca?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Nick stated, try and get one of the same value. If one of the same value is not available, you can always go up in CCA/ah, but never go down. Vehicles are spec'ed with a certain battery because that is what it needs to operate the starter to get the engine going. With a lower CCA/ah, you run the risk of dragging the starter, which can cause it damage. The specific CCA/ah also gives the accessories enough power without over taxing the alternator to keep up with the demand. It's kind of a symbiotic relationship.

The biggest thing you'll need to worry about is form factor. If the battery has too large of footprint it won't fit in the hole and allow you to bolt it down. If it's too tall, you won't be able to shut the hood, and shorting top post batteries across the hood is not a good thing ... think of thermal nuclear meltdown on an automobile scale.

Answer (score 2):

Try and get the same type. Since it's the amp's that cranks over the engine, you should try and get a minimum of 71ah as a 61ah won't last that long as it will struggle to get the starter working correctly - particularly in winter.

The 81ah battery is probably more expensive, and you won't see a massive improvement in battery life from the extra amps.